# Logical && versus bitwise & in Verilog

Tags: verilog, operator-keyword, logical-operators

Consider the following assignment

A1 = (b[3:0] ==c[3:0] & d[3:0]==e[3:0]) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0 ;

A2 = (b[3:0] ==c[3:0] && d[3:0]==e[3:0]) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0 ;

Are the 2  assignments equivalent or they could be different depending on tools?
Is it possible that (b[3:0] ==c[3:0]) evaluated as T/F is dependent on tool Whether it stores T as '1' or '0'.

Comment: I dont see a difference in simulation. But, I was told that using A1 assignment is not portable across synthesis tools.. Is that true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of the equality, relational and logical operators are defined in sections 11.4.4-7 of the IEEE 1800-2017 LRM. There is no room for implementation differences. *Truth* is defined as 1'b1, and *false* is defined as 1'b0.

Note there are slight differences in precedence between the logical and bitwise operators, and it's easy to mix them up when you start dealing with multiple bit results, so use the bitwise operators *only* if your intent is to deal with multi-bit results.